# How to fix the promise recieved instead of a plain object after fetching a data. everything is working good but there's that error in the console

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to pass a data from an API to the state using redux and a stateless component. The data fetches successfully but there's an error in the console.

```
mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(Home) must return a plain object. 
Instead received [object Promise]
```

Here's the corresponding code

```
/*************************************************/
// in the actions:

export function fetchPhotos(){
    const request = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
        .then(response=>response.json())

    return request.then(json=>({type: 'FETCH_PHOTOS', payload:json})
}

/****************************************************/
//in the reducer:

const album=[] 

const albumReducer=(state=album,action)=> {
   switch (action.type){
   case "FETCH_ALBUMS": return (action.payload);
   case "FETCH_PHOTOS": return (action.payload);

   default: return state
}

export default albumReducer.

/****************************************************/
// in the component

const mapStateToProps=(state)=> {
    return {
        PhotoList:state.albumReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=> {
    return bindActionCreators(fetchPhotos,dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(function PhotoList(props))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux by itself isn't setup to handle async actions like a data fetch request. Redux keeps it simple and focused. An action comes in, the reducer generates a new state from that action, the new state is used to re-render the UI. Rinse-repeat. The problem here is, the action is `fetchPhotos` which is the start of the fetch. The reducer cannot generate a new state that includes photos until the request is finished, and yet Redux isn't going to wait. After all, it has received an action and must generate a new state immediately.

Luckily this is not an uncommon problem and there are several solutions in the wild that can help you. The two most popular are [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

**Redux Saga**

- Has a pretty steep learning curve.
- Can (probably) handle more complex scenarios then redux-thunk
- Utilizes generators

**Redux Thunk**

- Very easy to read and reason about
- Utilizes async/await/promises

My recommendation is look at both libraries and see which one looks easier for you to dive into. Both can solve your dilemna. I think redux-thunk might be the simplest (and quickest) solution for you.

**Extra Tidbits**
Essentially what both these libraries do, is help you structure your async process in a sequential manner. So rather then generating a single action `fetchPhotos`, you split it up into steps. `fetchPhotosStart`, `fetchPhotosComplete`, `fetchPhotosFailed`. This way your reducer can handle each step independently, generating a new state and not being stuck waiting for a promise. When the promise eventually does resolve, you trigger the complete or failure action to update the store once more with the data or error message.

I find this extremely useful in that I can set `isLoading` when a request is started and display any spinners or progress bars I need. When the request completes, I set `isLoading` to `false` and also insert my data into the store.  For failures, I can set the error message in the store and show any error feedback UI my application may have.

So using your example, an extremely simplified example would be:

```
// in the actions:
// remove fetchPhotos since we only care about photos data
export function fetchPhotosSuccess(photos) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_PHOTOS_SUCCESS',
        payload: photos
    }
}

// in the component
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    fetchPhotos() {
        const self = this;
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => self.props.fetchPhotosSuccess(photos))
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(fetchPhotosSuccess, dispatch)
}
```

Hope this helps!